# Proof: Rank of block of matrix is smaller than rank of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, block-matrices

Let
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
A1 \\ A2\end{bmatrix}$$
be a matrix with real entries

Then proof $Rank(Ai) ≤ Rank(A)$ for $i = 1, 2$

---

I am attaching my solution sheet:
[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/su4D8.png)

Can someone help me understand the highlighted lines? How is "at least t pivots" guranteed?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $k$ rows of $A_1$ are independent then they are also independent in $A$.